# Excluding a library at runtime in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to have a library avilable at compiletime, but a remaped version at runtime,
how do i make it so eclipse doesn't add the compiletime library to the runtime classpath

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've already run this project at least once, so it appears in your `Run` menu. If so:

1. *Run menu* > *Run Configurations...*
2. Select the Run Configuration for your project in the left tree-table
3. Select the *Classpath* tab in the tabbed pane on the right hand-side.
4. Under *User Entries* select  *(default classpath)*
5. Click the *Remove* button
6. Select *User Entries* and click the *Add Projects...* button
7. Select  and click *OK*
8. Select  (under *User Entries*) and click *Add Jars...* to add back in the runtime libraries